Как получить правильную сортировку при группировке?
Есть исходные данные отсортированные по ID



id
book_id




306
51


305
48


304
51


303
48


302
51


301
51


300
13



MySQL: SELECT id, book_id FROM chapters ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
Laravel: Chapter::select('id', 'book_id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
Сейчас всё правильно, но без группировки.
Добавляем группировку в запрос:
MySQL: SELECT id, book_id FROM chapters group by book_id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5;
Laravel: Chapter::select('id', 'book_id')->groupBy('book_id')->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->take(5)->get();
И получаем на выходе



id
book_id




303
48


301
51


300
13


...
...



Вопрос: Как построить запрос так (MySQL or Laravel), что бы на выходе получить именно отсортированные по "id" и при этом без дубликатов "book_id" ?
То есть относительно исходной таблицы, нужно получить что-то такое:



id
book_id




306
51


305
48


300
13


...
...




Во втором запросе ты получаешь случайный id. В 99.99% случаев это не то что ты хочешь. Какой реальный результат ты пытаешься получить?

Возможно ты хочешь SELECT max(id), ...

Из-за случайности у меня и возникла проблема, мне необходимо получить последней id как в нижней таблице

https://onecompiler.com/mysql/432jf39zn

Спасибо, кажется это то, что надо!

А можете еще подсказать, как быть если сортируемое поле не числовое, а к примеру timestamp ? что бы к примеру сортировку произвести не по id а по created_at потому что есть ощущение, что оператор max() работает как-то не так с датой

нормально он работает для всех типов данных

-- Создаем таблицу
CREATE TABLE chapters (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  book_id INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- Добавляем данные в таблицу
INSERT INTO chapters (id, book_id) VALUES
(306,   51),
(305,   48),
(304,   51),
(303,   48),
(302,   51),
(301,   51),
(300,   13)
;

-- Выборка данных
SELECT 
    max(id) as id, 
    book_id 
FROM 
    chapters 
GROUP BY 
    book_id 
ORDER BY
    id DESC;

